# Storing JSON Metadata in mySQL/Mongo OR Postgres

Tags: mysql, json, mongodb, symfony, postgresql-9.4

I am working on project, where I would like to introduce metadata per category. That means I should be able to introduce different properties per category.

And when adding any product to the category it will allow me to save any fort of property and data I want.

Then at website these properties and values, that I want to save as JSON should be filterable.

I used Postgres earlier, for this sort of use case but never came to point to see it live for performance stage.

Comment: This might help you make a decision https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use [json_array from doctrine](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/types.html#json) (who is compatible with Postgresql) ?